# how to remove space in get id url using php

Tags: php, mysql, get

this code is working like this

> example.com/view.php?category=laptop&model=apple%20ipod

so i want like this (space remove)

> example.com/view.php?category=laptop&model=appleipod

how can i do this please help me to fix this issue thanks

```
      <?
$category = $_GET['category'];
$model = $_GET['model'];
    //connect to database

     mysql_connect('localhost','user','pass');
     mysql_select_db('datanew');


$result = mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); //the main trick
$q=mysql_query("select * from data where category='$category' And model='$model' AND TRIM(model) IS NOT NULL");

//Adds one to the counter
 mysql_query("UPDATE data SET counter = counter + 1 where category='$category' And model='$model'");

 //Retreives the current count
 $count = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT counter FROM data"));
$row=mysql_fetch_object($q);

echo mysql_error();


?>
<table class='hovertable'><?php if($row->model):?><tr class=\"style1\"><td width='200'><b>Model:</b></td><td><?php echo $row->model ?></td></tr><?php endif; ?>
<?php if($row->category):?><tr class=\"style1\"><td width='200'><b>Category:</b></td><td><?php echo $row->category?></td></tr><?php endif; ?></table>
```

Comment: What has the piece of code you posted to do with the generation of the URL? OR: Where is the origin of this URL problem in your code?

Comment: just use str_replace, and why do you want those removed anyway? do one of your rows have the literal `appleipod` (without spaces)?

Comment: I don't get it.. PHP Manual: urlencode(), urldecode(), str_replace(), htmlentities().

Comment: What is the problem that you are trying to solve? `$_GET` is already decoded so all these answers asking you to replace things won't work. Ask for help with your problem, not with what you think is the solution to your problem - see [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
  $model = str_replace(" ", "", $_GET['model']);
?>
```

Comment: $_GET vars are auto decoded, so this will translate to ` ` and not %20

Answer (score 1):

Use replace_str for replace all the space by nothing

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
<?php
  $model = str_replace(" ", "", $_GET['model']);
?>
```

Comment: `replace_str` new function?

Answer (score 1):

([Auto. urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php))
Use `str_replace(" ", "", $model);`

But I would recommend to do the work while building the url.
If you want to replace the whitespace for **building your url** than you can use `str_replace(" ", "", $myModelName);`.